# Are any other fittings backwards-compatible with ATSM F1974?

Tags: plumbing

[Doing some research for another question I asked](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/265481/5778), I think I understand that the fittings for tubing are standardized by [ASTM International.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASTM_International) Their [ASTM F1974 spec](https://standards.globalspec.com/std/14137473/ASTM%20F1974-09(2020)) is entitled,

> Standard Specification for **Metal Insert Fittings for Polyethylene/Aluminum/Polyethylene** and Crosslinked Polyethylene/Aluminum/Crosslinked Polyethylene Composite Pressure Pipe

I have an older pipe system which was discontinued called Kitec, manufactured by IPEX. Apparently the fittings it's supposed to use are F1974. I can't find them for sale anywhere. This isn't a shopping question either way. For the F1974 fittings is there any other kind of fittings that is reverse-compatible for it.

The reason for this question is that ASTM F1281 is labeled

> Standard Specification for Crosslinked Polyethylene/Aluminum/Crosslinked Polyethylene (PEX-AL-PEX) Pressure Pipe

and ASTM F1282,

> Standard Specification for Polyethylene/Aluminum/Polyethylene (PE-AL-PE) Composite Pressure Pipe

These numbers can be found on many fittings that do not say F1974, for example [this one on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/272023111660?hash=item3f55d747ec:g:TRcAAOSw5VFWJ9Un&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoOnS3iJr6i88HOdnpDOETY1GK4Vllb7G6s35jQQUASpA7IwOedrg633FPK6S04LKltxWulxTlxbQCb4Nrrq6e1GM50e0CuuvlknDlT7%2FwGW6h%2F%2B%2FUMCGIsHLQE8LnTFgqY7QRmr5aFkKKPF9VaEDkU6tNr8mwgxZsGQ3mUQ0DNo7Sy9Ga%2FUPfW7%2FVaByKYlGZ0NRGWqaE7mZGgnc6bOehOw%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR6DQ84XAYQ). I'm trying to find out *why* they don't say F-1974. And why it's so hard to find F-1974 fittings. My assumption, which may be wrong, is that there is a newer way to connect PEX-AL-PEX perhaps without an F-1974 metal-insert fitting?

Comment: search engine of choice, **pex-al-pex f1974 fittings**

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm using google. Mine shows a bunch of blue fin fittings, none of which are listed as f1974. Search on any page in that result set for 1974, I don't see it. They're just listed as "compression fittings". Most of those listings take you to SupplyHouse.com which must be like the biggest internet supplier, search there too for 1974, or f-1974, or f1974. All of those show nothing relevant.

Comment: https://www.dahlvalve.com/products/fittings/adapters/adapters-520-K3-PX3.php look at the specs tab.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that website only has 1/2 inch, and you can't buy it. I need 3/4 inch.